# malformed input when fetching Docker CE from repository

Tags: docker

I'm trying to install Docker CE from the official repository by executing:
`sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable"`

but output says `Malformed input, repository not added.`

What should I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by adding the repository to the list of sources manually.

Answer (score 0):

`echo -e "\ndeb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list`

as stated in https://gist.github.com/sethbergman/9ef9d14aef86ba7705791785ed377f69

Replace ubuntu with for example debian, if you're running debian instead.